# Bedeutung und Herkunft des Verbs »brakeln«

Tags: meaning, etymology, regional

Ich habe dieses Wort im Hamburger Raum öfter gehört und glaube, es ist ein Synonym zu *werkeln, herumbrezeln,* und *wurschteln.* Liege ich richtig? Und was ist die Herkunft dieses Worts?

Comment: Ich habe inzwischen vier (gebürtige) Hamburger gefragt und keiner kennt das Wort... @Susilapitschie, hast du einen ganzen Beispielsatz zu dem Verb?

Comment: Brakel ist ein Ort zwischen Boffzen und Altenbeken, insofern könnte Brakeln, analog zum Berlinern, das Sprechen des Dialekts der Region sein, wie 'Was het misschien een scheld- of een vies woord dat daarom onleesbaar gemaakt is?'

Comment: Ich sehe gerade, in Belgien gibt es eine ganze Stadt namens Brakel, und die Textprobe stammt von einer belgischen Url - man brakelt also, wenn, dann eher in Belgien so. :)

Answer (score 3):

*Brakel* scheinen einerseits eine Hühnerrasse zu sein, siehe [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brakel_(Huhn)) oder auch [hier](http://www.huehner-info.de/forum/showthread.php/55167-Ziehen-Zwerg-Brakeln-hohe-B%C3%A4ume-zur-%C3%9Cbernachtung-dem-H%C3%BChnerstall-vor). Andererseits kommen *Brakeln* noch in einem Kinderbuch vor, wo sie als [süß schmeckende Rüben beschrieben werden](https://books.google.de/books?id=mSkaAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22brakeln%22&source=bl&ots=Jy6qycrBQi&sig=VMyc97erh-0HkitL-tAdTIG4lkM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFmtCMh6fKAhXFnA4KHUEpC1YQ6AEIQzAG#v=onepage&q=%22brakeln%22&f=false).

*Brakeln* als Verb ist mir in fünf Jahren Norddeutschland nicht begegnet. Ich könnte mir höchstens eine Bedeutung in Richtung *gackern*, *plaudern* vorstellen, und dann nur sehr lokal.

Als Wort für *wurschteln*, *werkeln* etc. kenne ich aus dem norddt. Raum eher *prökeln* bzw. *brökeln*.

PS: Das beantwortet nicht zwingend deine Frage, aber durch meine Links ist mein Beitrag zu lang für einen Kommentar, deshalb habe ich es als Antwort gepostet.